# Kubernetes HPA memory autoscale does not work

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

As mentioned in doc, HPA apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1 support memory autoscale, but it does not work for me. Any help is highly appreciated.

HPA:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
    kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
    metadata:
      name: xxx
    spec:
      scaleTargetRef:
        apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
        kind: Deployment
        name: xxx
        minReplicas: 1
        maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        targetAverageUtilization: 70
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        targetAverageValue: 1050Mi`

Deployement.yml:
    `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: xxx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: xxx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: xxx
        image:  xxx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1024M"
            cpu: "500m"
          limits:
            memory: "2048M"
            cpu: "1000m"
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /swagger-ui.html
            port: 9002
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 180
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /swagger-ui.html
            port: 9002
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 5
```

`$kubectl describe hpa`

```
Metrics:                                               ( current / target )
  resource memory on pods:                             1343959859200m / 1050Mi
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  4% (28m) / 70%
Min replicas:                                          1
Max replicas:                                          10
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason              Message
  ----            ------  ------              -------
  AbleToScale     True    ReadyForNewScale    the last scale time was sufficiently old as to warrant a new scale
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound    the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from memory resource
  ScalingLimited  False   DesiredWithinRange  the desired count is within the acceptable range
Events:           <none>
```

`$kubectl get hpa`

```
NAME                    REFERENCE                          TARGETS                          MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
xxx   Deployment/xxx   1551148373333m/1050Mi, 98%/70%   1         10        3          42m
```

`$kubectl version`

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.7", GitCommit:"0c38c362511b20a098d7cd855f1314dad92c2780", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-20T10:09:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.5-gke.5", GitCommit:"9aba9c1237d9d2347bef28652b93b1cba3aca6d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-11T02:36:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Gcloud information:

```
[compute]
    region: [us-east1]
    zone: [us-east1-b]
```

As displayed, K8S understand how much memory is over target value but does not autoscale pods even I have waited for a long time. I only auto-scale with CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the Autoscaler works with CPU only, when you deployed the HPA, did you only set the CPU metric?

After reading the HPA Walkthrough documentation in k8s, I noticed that when setting multiple metrics all of the them must be reached to scale, refer to this section:

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-multiple-metrics-and-custom-metrics

So in your case, the Autoscaler must meet both conditions the CPU and memory usage metric.

Comment: HPA apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1 support memory autoscale too. According your link, i did not see where it states that: "I noticed that when setting multiple metrics all of the them must be reached to scale". Also, there is case memory reach to a certain level whereas CPU does not go with.

Comment: It's implicit, you can notice if you read one of the examples provided, it seems like when using multiple conditions all of them must be met to scale or the autoscaler ensures that all pods run under them. It's the second example: "For example, if you had your monitoring system collecting metrics about network traffic, you could update the definition above using kubectl edit to look like this"